# asp.net dynamically loaded

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005

I am having some problem in my data base connection when I am trying to dynamically load my page using data grid view in asp.net i am getting some error like:-

> An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server.
>   When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be caused by the
>   fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote
>   connections.  provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not
>   open a connection to SQL Server

Comment: check whether SQL Server service is running up and you connected the the correct server.

Comment: yaa shyju its running properly but not connectinng plzzz help me

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to the correct Instance? Post your connection string.

Comment: {
        SqlCommand com=new SqlCommand("select *from sandeep",new SqlConnection("data source=SQLEXEPRESS;initial catalog=deepu;integrated security=true"));
        try
        {
            com.Connection.Open();
            GridView1.DataSource = com.ExecuteReader();
            GridView1.DataBind();
            com.Connection.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Label1.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable named pipes on the SQl Server configuration manager:

[image]

there is a far more complex explanation [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/)

Comment: hey diego i have enabled the named pipes but error is same :-(

Comment: hey finally i have sucessed to connect my database and im getting my result ...... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [How to configure SQL Server 2005 to allow remote connections](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277) and [this thread in the SQL Server forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/2a8f2e64-74cf-46f2-b2be-bbb08b1502cb/).

Comment: i have already done these execercise but i am always getting error and error again .